# What is called a "monoid" with extra operations, e.g. $(M,e,+,*,\times)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

This question is a bit odd, but I'm quite juvenile in abstract algebra, so perhaps someone can understand what I mean and help out.

So, a monoid is a triple $(M,*,e)$ where $M$ is a set, $e$ is a neutral element and $*$ is a binary operator where:
$$
a * (b * c) = (a*b)*c
$$
$$
a* e = e*a
$$

Now, suppose that I can also define an operation $+$ and $\times$, such that $\forall m,n \in M $ we have $m+n \in M$ and $m\times n \in M$, and also, $m+n = n +m$,
$$
m \times (n + l) = m\times n + m \times l
$$

$$
m \times n \neq n \times m
$$

$$
m * (n_1 + n_2) = m * n_1 + m * n_2
$$

$$
m* (n_1\times n_2) \neq (m *n_1) \times (m * n_2)
$$

Hence, I have $(M,e,*,+,\times)$. My question then is what is this thing called? I'm trying to learn more about such structures, cause I actually have something like this in a program that I'm coding.

Just to give more perspective. The $*$ operator is like a composition, where $m*n$ means something like $m$ is parent of $n$.
The $+$ is like an "append", and the $\times$ creates a new object.

Here is an actual example. Consider the category of all sets. Hence, $M$ is the class of all sets. The operator $*$ is the "nesting" operator. For example:
$$
A := \{1,2\} \quad,B := \{a,b\} \implies 
A * B = \{1,2,\{a,b\}\}
$$

$$
A \times B = \{\{1,a\},\{1,b\},\{2,a\},\{2,b\}\}
$$
$$
A + B = \{1,2,a,b\}
$$

Comment: I don't think that there is a standard, common name, but "monoid with extra operations" sounds understandable to me.

Comment: I want to know the mathematical properties of such things. Hence a name is just a way to help me search references.

Comment: @Beautifullyirrational, not really...

Comment: @Beautifullyirrational, the answer talks mostly about things with two operations, and not closed on the three.

Comment: I mean you can stack as many operation as you want. I can't remember exactly but I think this is called universal algebra. Only when you have interaction rules between the  different operation (think how multip distributes over addition) that the higher structures I showed before comes

Comment: This doesn’t mean much without some relation between the two operations (distribution for example).

Comment: “is a parent of” is a sort of relation, not a binary operation.

Comment: It's actually like composition. $m * n \cong m (n)$.